# How can I make pretty URL link with wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting

I've got some questions about making pretty URL link.

On my website home page, I have a drop down list of text (city and state) which is going to be my parameter. I'm sending the value through **GET METHOD to a WordPress template page** which system will display contents based on passed value. The display content part is working successfully, however, I have some question about link.

Right now, the link of the page is showing

www.mydomain.com/list/?state=NY&city=Newyork or
www.mydomain.com/list/?state=IL&city=Chicago

I prefer the link to be the following pretty format, ...
www.mydomain/list/NY/Newyork
www.mydomain/list/IL/Chicago

I have researched on many sites and found recommendation on using htaccess. I'm using the following code but still link doesn't get changed to the pretty format.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/?$ ?district=$1
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?district=$1&templename=$2 [L]
</IfModule> 

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Links can become 'pretty' via backoffice> preferences> Permalinks. There you can specify the format of your links for single and category pages. Clicking on save preferences will overwrite your htaccess to the wished format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for should be done using wordpress' `add_rewrite_rule` function. You can read more about it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Here's a sample that may be what you're looking for:

```
<?php 
add_rewrite_rule('list/([0-9|a-z|A-Z]*)?/?([0-9|a-z|A-Z]*)?/?([0-9|a-z|A-Z]*)?/?([0-9|a-z|A-Z]*)?','index.php?$matches[1]=$matches[2]&$matches[3]=$matches[4]','top');
?>
```

To explain things in detail:

1. First, we declare a regular expression to match any get parameters after the "list" slug. (i.e: www.mydomain.com/list/)
2. Secondly, we declare how wordpress should interpret it. The file will always be index.php for wordpress. The parameters will line up like `www.mydomain.com/list/state/IL/city/Chicago` which will translate to `www.mydomain.com/list/?state=IL&city=Chicago` in your code for you to use your $_GET parameters
3. `top` tells Wordpress that these rules have **precedence** over wordpress' own rules.

You may need to call `flush_rewrite_rules( false )` or `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules()` to flush the rules and have your changes come into effect

Comment: Cool!! I adapted my code by your suggestion. It's work!!. Thank you. @TheJokersThief